# Pigeonhole principle for finding consecutive days in which exactly $33$ tasks are performed

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

I am supposed to solve the following problem by pigeonhole principle:

Peter ​​solves at least one task per day for three months before the MO regional round. He does not solve more than $13$ tasks per calendar week. Prove that you can find several consecutive days during which student has solved, exactly $33$ tasks!

What I tried:

There is $12$ weeks in a $3$ months period. By this time, he is able to solve $12 \cdot 13= 156$ problems. But I do not know how to continue.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Consecutive days of what?

Comment: @Mike I updated it

Comment: Aren't there $13$ weeks in a three-month period?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I do not understad, there is 12 or?

Comment: There are $52$ weeks (and one day) in a $12$-month (non-leap) year, so there are approximately $52/4 = 13$ weeks in three months.

Comment: This is a pretty standard [pigeonhole](https://brilliant.org/wiki/pigeonhole-principle-definition/) problem. Given the tags, how have you tried to use it?

Comment: I stand corrected I thought it was standard, but had an error with the number of weeks, and couldn't push through when I started fixing it.

Comment: See here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1853532/pigeonhole-principle-question-jessica-the-combinatorics-student?rq=1

Comment: @Azlif I tried to push through with that setup, but wasn't able to. I do believe this problem is true, but we need a stronger way to deal with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a solution to the current problem.
Using the standard setup, I will show that

1. With at most 13 tasks per calander week, over 15 weeks, then there is a series of days with exactly 33 tasks.
2. With at most 12 tasks per calander week, over 13 weeks, then there is a series of days with exactly 33 tasks.

In either case, this standard setup doesn't allow us to reduce the number of weeks.

I suspect the following statement is true (and possibly something stronger), as I cannot find a counter example:
3. With at most 13 tasks per calander week, over 13 weeks, then there is a series of days with exactly 33 tasks.

Note: Obviously if we're allowed 14 tasks per week, then we could do 2 a day and never get a series of days with exactly 33 tasks.

---

Proof of 1:
Let $t_i$ be the number of tasks done on day $i$.
Let $T_i = \sum_{j=1}^i t_j $ be the cumulative number of tasks done by day $i$.
We have $1 \leq T_1 < T_2 < \ldots < T_{105} \leq 195$.

Let our pigeons be $T_i$. There are 105 of them.
Let our pigeonholes be the sets of the form $\{ 66k + i, 66k+i+33 \}$. Since $66 \times 3 = 198 > 195$, there are 99 of them.
So, by PP, there are 2 piegons in 1 hole, which gives us $T_j = T_i + 33$.

---

Proof of 2.
Set up in a similar manner.
We have $1 \leq T_1 < T_2 < \ldots < T_{91} \leq 156$.
Let our pigeons be $T_i$. There are 91 of them.
Let our pigeonholes be the sets of the form $\{ 66k + i, 66k+i+33 \}$. Since $156 = 2\times 66 + 24$, there are $66 + 24 = 90$ of them.
So, by PP, there are 2 piegons in 1 hole, which gives us $T_j = T_i + 33$.

---

Thoughts on 3.

There are 91 pigeons and 99 holes.
We have 8 degrees of freedom in choosing the values of $T_i$.

Comment: Thank you so much, maybe there is a mistake in the book, and that is why it does not make sense, for those numbers

Comment: Depends. If this is meant to be a standard exercise, then go with case 1 or 2. If the book delves much deeper into PP, then case 3 might still be valid. The restriction of "13 problems in a week" is extremely strong.

Comment: okay, thank you